# Number of distinct digits

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many integers from 10 through 99 have distinct digits?

Solution using the Multiplication Rule:
[# of ints w/ dist. digits] = [# ways to pick digit 1] * [# ways to pick digit 2].
Since there are 9 ways to determine the 1st digit and (10 – 1 = 9) ways to determine the second digit,
[9] * [9] = 81
So there are 81 integers from 10-99 with distinct digits.

I'm not understanding the part where it says the "# of ways to pick digit 1 or 2". Are the numbers coming from the fact that the ones digit from 10 to 19 are 10 numbers total? But why 9? I've always been bad with numbers.. so apologies if this is common sense, but I really do not understand where these numbers came from (9*9 for example)

Answer (score 2):

The solution skips some steps. And what makes it really confusing is that $9$ occurs twice, for two different reasons. Here they are:

- There are $9$ ways to pick the first digit because the number range starts at $10$ and ends at $99$, so the first digit can be anywhere from $1-9$.
- There are $9$ ways to pick the second digit, for a completely different reason. There are ten digits in total, but we're not allowed pick a digit equal to the first one. So we have $10-1 = 9$ options, hence the $9$ in this case.

Now you multiply together and you get your answer, $81$. Please comment if you need further clarification.

---

As an aside, this can be solved in a different way, which is good for checking the answer. Note that there are $90$ digits between $10$ and $99$, inclusive. Now notice that the ones that *do* have repeats are $11, 22, 33, \dots, 99$. Clearly, there are $9$ of these. Now, the numbers with no repeats are the total, minus those with repeats. So you have $90 - 9 = 81$. A nice assurance that the above is correct.

Answer (score 1):

We have $9$ choices of the first digit, since we know it's either $1,2,3...$ up to $9$ (if it were $0$, it would be a one digit number). After picking the $10$'s digit, we've fixed it: we know what it is, so we can say that it is, arbitrarily $x$ where $x \in \{1,2,3...9\}$. Without any constraint, the $1$'s digit could be anything from $0$ to $9$, giving $10$ choices, including $x$. However, since I don't want the ones where the digits are the same, I take out the option for the $1$'s digit to be $x$, leaving me $9$ choices.